# In P4V, how do I create a branch from a label?

Tags: label, branch, perforce, p4v

My company just imported our `CVS` repository into Perforce. I'm new to P4V and I can't work out how to create a branch from an existing label. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In my copy of P4V (Version 2013.3), I go to the `Actions` menu and choose `Branch Files...`, which brings up the `Branch Files` dialog:

[image]

In that dialog, I specify the source files to branch, and the target name of my branch (in my case I am branching `//depot/main/...` to `//depot/branch/...`), and in the `Filter` tab I specify that I want to specify the source revisions using a label.

And I type my label name into the text box (If I don't know the label name I can `Browse...` for it).

Then I click the `Branch` button to make the branch.